# Consumer isAuthenticated doesn't get updated when set bya function in AuthContext

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, react-context

I'm trying to get my navigation bar to update the signout button when the user is authenticated. I'm using React Context to keep track of the isAuthenticated value. I wrapped my AuthProvider in layout.tsx and page.tsx (root file). I have other components. Could this be an asynchronous or scope issue? I tried using useEffect to keep track of global changes.

```
// AuthContext.tsx
...

export const AuthProvider: React.FC<AuthProviderProps> = ({ children }: AuthProviderProps) => {
    const [isAuthenticated, setIsAuthenticated] = useState(false)

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(isAuthenticated)
    }, [isAuthenticated])

    const login = async () => {
        setIsAuthenticated(true);
        console.log("Logged in user")
    }

    const logout = async () => {
        setIsAuthenticated(false)
        console.log("Logged out user")
    }

    return (
        <AuthContext.Provider value={{ isAuthenticated, login, logout }}>
            {children}
        </AuthContext.Provider>
    );
};
```

```
// Navigation.tsx
...

export default function Navigation() {
    const { isAuthenticated, login } = useAuth();
    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(isAuthenticated)
    }, [isAuthenticated, login])

    return (
        <nav className='bg-white border-b border-gray-200 py-4 shadow-sm'>
            <ul className='flex justify-center space-x-10'>
                {navCategories.map((category) => (
                    <li key={category.label} className='text-gray-600 hover:text-blue-600'>
                        <Link href={category.href}>
                            <span className='text-md font-semibold tracking-wide transition-colors duration-300'>
                                {category.label}
                            </span>
                        </Link>
                    </li>
                ))}
            </ul>
            {isAuthenticated &&
                <Signout />
            }
        </nav>
    )
}
```

```
// layout.tsx
...

export default function RootLayout({
    children,
}: Readonly<{
    children: React.ReactNode;
}>) {
    return (
        <html lang="en">
            <body className={inter.className}>
                <AuthProvider>
                    <Navigation />
                </AuthProvider>
                {children}
            </body>
        </html>
    );
}
```

Comment: Hi Han ! Have you checked the below answer? Let us know please :)

Answer (score 0):

You should call `AuthProvider` once, and wrap `children` as well, so that any update is made in the same context:

```
export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: Readonly<{
  children: React.ReactNode;
}>) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body className={inter.className}>
        <AuthProvider>
          <Navigation />
          {children}
        </AuthProvider>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

Remove the provide call in `page.tsx`, because as done above, the context is accessible to every component. And having it called once, ensure you refer to the same context value.